# Accessing an element of an object in an arraylist

Tags: java, object, element

I am working with an `ArrayList` of objects that contain multiple variables. For example:

```
// pseudo code
class Ticket {    
    int gameID
    double price
    int seatnumber
}
```

and I have an `ArrayList` of multiple `Ticket` objects and need to access them. I've looked at the javadoc and so far I have come up with

```
list.get(index).attribute
```

However I get a compile-error saying:

> cannot find symbol

am I doing something wrong with the syntax?
here is my code:

```
public static void printGameMoney(ArrayList games, ArrayList tickets)
{
    double total = 0;
    double tickMoney = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<tickets.size(); i++)
    {           
        double tickMoney = tickets.get(i).priceOfTick;
        total = total + tickMoney;          
    }
}
```

Comment: Errors depends on what you wrote. Show the full codes please.

Comment: Please show your code, and mark the line where you're getting the error.

Comment: Write your true code, not pseudo one. No one will try to guess what happens in your code if you don't show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If attribute is really one of your class member then please use as follow.

```
((Ticket) list.get(index)).attribute;
```

Comment: That's just guessing, isn't it?

Comment: tried it out and it worked! thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You code is *"old-school"*, you should use typed-types, interfaces and new style for-loop:

```
public static void printGameMoney(final List<Game> games, final List<Ticket> tickets)
{
    double total = 0;

    for (final Ticket ticket : tickets)
    {           
        final double tickMoney = ticket.getPriceOfTick();
        total = total + tickMoney;          
    }
}
```

Also note this method is strange as it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```
public static void printGameMoney(ArrayList games, ArrayList<Ticket> tickets)
{
    double total = 0;
    double tickMoney = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<tickets.size(); i++)
    {           
        double tickMoney = tickets.get(i).priceOfTick;
        total = total + tickMoney;          
    }
}
```

Basically, the change leads to `ArrayList<Ticket>` instead of simple `ArrayList`. This way you tell the compiler that objects inside your `ArrayList` are of `Ticket` type, therefore they have attributes you specified (e.g. `priceOfTick`).

Same goes for `games`, so if you have `Game` class, you should use `ArrayList<Game> games`.

Comment: thanks a lot, this is a method where the ArrayList is being passed into from the main program

Comment: No problem. Please, consider voting for answers which you found useful.

Answer (score 1):

Start by putting semicolons after each field declaration:

```
class Ticket {    
    int gameID;
    double price;
    int seatnumber;
}
```

Also, show the exact code you're using instead of `list.get(index).attribute`.

Comment: the class code is pseudo code, and this is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: He wrote it's pseudo code so I don't think that's the case.

Comment: @PiotrChojnacki I formatted it as code, so I added "pseudo code"

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
((Ticket)list.get(x)).attribute;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to access like this ,`list.get(i).price;`  not `list.price.get(i);`

```
for (int i=0; i<tickets.size(); i++)
{

    double tickMoney =  list.get(i).price;
    total = total + tickMoney;  

}
```

Here problem is that with your deceleration of `ArrayList`

If you declare like `ArrayList<Ticket>` you need  not to cast there while getting.  Other wise you need a cast there. More over use for each loop.